# Magento 2 What is the different between setDefaultOrder and SetSortBy in layout xml?

Tags: magento2, layout, product-sorting

I'm trying to set a default sort order to products listing in category page.

I have seen people suggest using

```
            <action method="setDefaultOrder">
                <argument name="sort" xsi:type="string">name</argument>
            </action>
                <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                    <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">asc</argument>
                </action>
```

or by using

```
            <action method="setSortBy"><string>name</string></action>
                <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                    <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">asc</argument>
                </action>
```

Unfortunately none of the above method worked for me. But I just want to know what's the different between setDefaultOrder and setSortBy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you've got one of those snippets from

https://www.customerparadigm.com/changing-default-product-sorting-in-magento-2/

app/design/frontend/{{Vendor_Namespace}}/{{Theme_Name}}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:nonamespaceschemalocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <referencecontainer name="content">
            <referenceblock class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list">
                <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                    <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceblock>
        </referencecontainer>
    </page>
```

That's to change sort by direction

To change sort by value

Stores > Config > Catalog > Catalog > Storefront > Product Listing Sort By